# How to retrieve view of last position clicked in RecyclerViewAdapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerViewAdapter` class for a list of songs and on when I touch a song, the background of that song becomes blue. The problem is that if I try to touch a different song, that song will also become blue, but I cannot find a solution to change the previously touched song in my list to change the `CardView`  back so that only one item at a time will be blue at any given touch.

Within :

```
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {


            final ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) holder;

            viewHolder.setImageResourceType(mList, position);
            viewHolder.getTxtViewTitle().setText(mList.get(position).getTitle());
            viewHolder.getTxtViewArtist().setText(mList.get(position).getArtist());
            viewHolder.getTxtViewDuration().setText(MusicUtil.GetDurationHMS(mList.get(position).getDuration()));
            viewHolder.getCardView().setCardBackgroundColor(Color.argb(0, 0, 0, 0));


            viewHolder.getCardView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    mListener.onRecyclerViewItemClicked(viewHolder, position, view.getId());

                    viewHolder.getCardView().setCardBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

                    mLastPosition = position; // To be used to store last position clicked
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: you want whatever you touch in Recylerview become blue ? Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: why are you changing the color in the adapter and you have a Listener?

Comment: Saving the last clicked position and trying to retrieve the view later (ex : using `recyclerview.getChildAt(position)`) will cause crashes if last selected view is is recycled already

Comment: @FaizMir yes, but only the last touched item only like in a menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manage a `lastHolder` global variable in your adapter class.

```
viewHolder.getCardView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    mListener.onRecyclerViewItemClicked(viewHolder, position, view.getId());

                    viewHolder.getCardView().setCardBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

                    mLastPosition = position; // To be used to store last position clicked
                    if(lastHolder!=null)
                     {
                        // do your task here which you want to do for previous selection


         lastHolder.getCardView().setCardBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                     }
                     lastHolder=viewHolder;
                }
            });
```

Comment: Just tested it and that works perfectly only keeping the last touched item background blue, while returning the previously touched item background to its original color.